# WPF. Остановить выполнение приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно остановить дальнейшее выполнение приложения?
Например:

```
public string LinkParser(string link)
    {
        string playlistId = default;
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(link);
            playlistId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("list");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect link");
        }
        

        return playlistId;
    }
```

B catch добавить какую-то инструкцию которая останавливала бы работу программы, метод не возвращал значение, и дальше ничего не выполнялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Incorrect link");
    throw ex;
}
```

В вызывающем методе оберните код в `try-catch`, в таком случае вы сможете попасть в конец кода метода, чтобы дальше ничего не выполнялось.